# Why Jainism, Buddhism and Sikhism require to do blasphemy against our dharma and God like shri ram,hanuman and shri krishna to promote their faith?

Tags: scripture, buddhism, jainism, sikhism

I have respected Jainism, buddhism and Sikhism from childhood, but now, I only tolerate them (due to current law)because their scriptures are blasphemous against shri hari and mahadev avtars.

> Now Daśānana with Śambūka and Lakṣmaṇa are in the fourth hell. For
> people’s conditions of existence ace subject to karma. After
> experiencing their life in hell
>
> Book VII - Jain Ramayana (Rāmāyaṇa),Chapter X - Rāma’s mokṣa
> (emancipation),Part 12: Future births of Rāvaṇa, Lakṣmaṇa, and Sītā
>
> Rāma had four chief-queens: Maithilī, Prabhāvatī, Ratinibhā, and
> Śrīdāmā, the fourth.
>
> Book VII - Jain Ramayana (Rāmāyaṇa),Chapter VIII - The abandonment of
> Sītā,Part 11: Rāma’s household
>
> Once upon a time, at Benares, a great king named Dasaratha renounced
> the ways of evil, and reigned in righteousness. ***Of his sixteen
> thousand wives, the eldest and queen-consort bore him two sons and a
> daughter;the elder son was named Rama-paṇḍita, or Rama the Wise, the
> second was named Prince Lakkhaṇa, or Lucky, and the daughter's name
> was the Lady Sītā***
>
> The Jataka, Vol. IV: No. 461.: Dasaratha-Jātaka.
>
> Hanuman burnt the fortress of Sri Lanka, uprooted the garden of
> Raawan, and brought healing herbs for the wounds of Lachhman, pleasing
> Lord Raamaa;and yet, because of his karma, he could not be rid of his
> loin cloth. ||5||
>
> Sri Guru Granth Sahib Ji - Ang 695
>
> The Hindu is sightless; the Muslim has only one eye.
>
> Sri Guru Granth Sahib Ji - Ang 875

Now, all these statements from their scriptures arises many questions

1. Should blasphemy by whole community be accepted or not? Why could not they just promote their  faith without interfering others? Also by recitation of their scriptures do they accumulate bad karma?
2. We do not blaspheme their Tirthankara or Buddhist or Sikh guru in our scripture. So why they did this?
3. How should one respond if they start quoting against our God in blasphemous manner?
   [Like in my case a Jain told me you are praying to Krishna who is in hell.]

> Engaging in cruel meditation to this effect for a moment, his life of
> a thousand years completed, Kṛṣṇa went to the third hell which he had
> acquired formerly by karma that must be experienced.
>
> Book VIII - Nemināthacaritra (Jain Harivamsa),Chapter XI - burning of
> dvārakā and the death of kṛṣṇa,Part 4: Death of Kṛṣṇa

PS: The Hindu is sightless. The context of this is calling Hindu rituals superstitious, like idol worshipping, tirthas, polytheism etc.

Comment: This can not be answered on this site. It is off topic for this site. Some other faith complaining about Hinduism, means only they can answer.

Answer (score 2):

Such verses are simply the result of communal tensions between those religions and Hinduism which took place in the earlier times and consequently led to the composition of such verses in their respective literatures.

An analogous situation would be how The texts of Shaivism and Vaishnavism themselves demean and belittle either [each other's diety](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57007/33985) or [each other's followers,scriptures and practices](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58176/33985) at several places

So one word answer - Fanaticism

Answer (score -1):

As everyone knows, half knowledge is more harmful than no knowledge. The same book which says krishna is in hell or something similar, also says that krishna did so much good work for society that krishna will attain the highest state (arihant) according to them in next birth.

They are not promoting hate against anyone but lay emphasis on law of karma. Even in hindu books, there are stories where gods have to come down on earth as a result of there deeds.

Again, I would stress that instead of picking up controversial lines, please read those books or consult gurus, who read those books. Keep in mind, krishna/rama/mahavir/hanuman are parts of same conciousness. They represent different schools of philosophies, that were popular during different time periods.

Comment: No[manu 12-95,96] they are not same

Comment: also, doesn't it make your religion false by making truth a lie like shri ram had only wife devi sita. But in your scripture, it's written 4 wives. Doesn't this make your religion  false.  Like after centuries of ramayan , you say ramayan plot is something else. Doesn't this obviously make it to fact that jainism is false religion

Comment: @Hope grow up please! I am not representing any religion here. Nor do I want to get into pointless debates here. IMO, religion is here to enable humans to become better and better. Picking up one line from any book and start critizing it, doesnt make any sense. I initially answered this question because I studied many such inscriptions from gurus of both hindus and jains. Anyways, good luck on your path of knowledge.

Comment: You can downvote, flag or do anything. But still you should answer question about shri ram. Like it doesn't make sense like laxman killed ravan and ram had 4 wives. Also, it is your scripture giving contexr to other and saying other in hell. Not vice versa.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Copying references from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58164/4596), we can see that just as Jain, Buddhist and Sikh scriptures may have polemical content against Hinduism, Hindu scriptures too may have polemical content against other religions.

And as proven by Brihaspati's answer, Hindu schools may have polemical content against each other too.

Hence, one should not get too emotional about it.

[Padma purana bhumi khanda ch 38](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364245.html)

> 25-30. When Kali (-yuga) sets in, all men, deluded by sins, will act
> after having resorted to the Jaina faith. Men will abandon Vedic
> practices, and will commit sins. There is no doubt that the Jaina
> faith is the root of sin. O best king, the fall of those men, who are
> heaps of sins, is brought about by this great delusion. Govinda (i.e.
> Viṣṇu), the destroyer of all sins, will be (appearing) for their
> destruction and for nothing else. Taking the form of his liking he
> will restrain (them) from sins. When sins wil have thus accumulated,
> he, the god will be (appearing) as Kalki[3](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/37/) for the destruction of the
> Mlecchas; there is no doubt about it. Give up the behaviour of (i.e.
> proper for) Kali (-yuga) and resort to merit. Behave truthfully;
> become the guardian of your subjects.

[SB 2.7.37](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/37/)

> When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
> knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
> in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
> the Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
> Buddha and will preach on subreligious principles.

[Agni Purana 16.2-4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083104.html)

> 2. They sought refuge in the lord saying, “Protect us! Protect us!”. He (Viṣṇu), who is of the form of illusory delusion became the son of
>    Śuddhodana. 3-4. He deluded those demons. Those, who had abandoned the
>    path laid down in the Vedas, became the Bauddhas and from them others
>    who had abandoned the Vedas. He then became the Arhat (Jaina). He then
>    made others as Arhats. Thus the heretics came into being devoid of
>    vedic dharmas.

[Vayu Purana II.17.24-25](https://archive.org/details/the-vayu-purana-part-2-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/page/620/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

**Kalki Purana 10.30**[image]